# Mule: knowing what component/endpoint threw an exception with default catch exception

Tags: java, mule, mule-el

I have a default catch exception strategy for my entire flow/subflows. However, I'd like to be able to tell what component/endpoint threw an exception so I can try to restart the flow at that point (I have yet to figure out how to do that as well.)

Is there any easy way to tell what component/endpoint threw the exception, and be able to tell if it was in a foreach, and at what point (by looking at the "counter" variable.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable at the start of flow like this:

```
<set-variable variableName="flowName" value="Your_flow_name"/>
```

And the get the flow name like `#[flowName]` in your exception strategy.

EDIT:

To trigger a flow, create a java component implementing `Callable` interface, from the `context` get the `MuleClient` and use `send` or `dispatch` method to send payload to flow. `Send` causes MuleClient to wait for response while `dispatch` doesn't.

More info here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+the+Mule+Client

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And from there, in the exception, is there a way I can restart the flow using #[flowName] in some way?

Comment: To trigger a flow, you can get `MuleClient` from context and then use `dispatch` or `send` with payload. Updated my answer

Comment: Any idea how I can get the error message from the default catch exception? That would help me figure out what the error was and whether to restart the flow or not.

Comment: Exception is available in `#[exception]` variable. You can also use `#[exception.summaryMessage]`

Comment: When trying to log #[exception.summaryMessage], I'm getting the following error:
org.mule.api.MessagingException: [Error: Missing left node]
[Near : {... error occured: ' + #[exception.summaryMessage], 'e ....}]

Are you sure it is valid?

Comment: Yes it is if the `exception` is not null. I'd say open another question for your doubt

Comment: Figured it out. I was using nested #[]